# Deformed mesh when applying weigth

Tags: bones

I downloaded a Skeleton , and a helm model with another skeleton, I deleted the models skeleton, and try to put the one I want as parent, if I do this by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>  Bones, or bones relative, then  in pose mode the helm in this case moves as intended, but when I export the file, it says it has no bones

I tried with automatic weight's and it gives me an error.

I tried with envelop weights, and here it moves but it gets deformed, because some meshes stays in place (like the decals) and the helm itself moves.

How do I fix this? I m terribly lost.